# Configuration System failed to Initialize exception in migrated project to .net5

Tags: c#

I have migrated my WinForms application in .NET framework 4.7 to .NET5.0 using the upgrade-assistant utility. However, after migrating, when I try to run migrated application in debug mode, i am getting the exception "Configuration System Failed to Initialize", while trying to read the data from the "Properties.Settings" file present in the class library.

But, when I created a sample win forms project in .NET5, I am able to read the data from the "Properties.Settings" file.

Answer (score 0):

Used the following way to read the value from the properties Settings file:

```
<PropertySettingName>.Default.Properties[<PropertyKey>].DefaultValue.ToString()
```